# Problem with table lines in a footer

Tags: tables, header-footer, vertical-alignment

Hello dear LaTeX users,

I'm having difficulties with table horizontal lines positions. I'm using a table in a footer to obtain such an composition with page number:

[image: http://prntscr.com/9f0jdo]

While everything works fine for odd pages (as above), for even pages the bottom line is shifted down, not connecting with other ones:

[image]

I have no idea what is wrong - the table code is the same for odd and even pages. I would be glad for any help - this may be a detail, but it's really annoying. Here's a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{red-fiz}{RGB}{194,0,11}
\usepackage{array,multirow}
\usepackage[left=3.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{3pt} 
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[RO]{
    \arrayrulecolor{red-fiz}
    \begin{tabular}{m{0.91\textwidth}|m{0.03\textwidth}}
        \cline{2-2}
        & \multirow{2}{0.03\textwidth}{\thepage} \\ [0.03\textwidth]
        \cline{1-1}
    \end{tabular}}
\fancyfoot[LE]{
    \arrayrulecolor{red-fiz}
    \begin{tabular}{m{0.03\textwidth}|m{0.91\textwidth}}
        \cline{1-1}\vspace{-10pt}
        \multirow{2}{0.03\textwidth}{\thepage} & \\ [0.03\textwidth]
        \cline{2-2}
    \end{tabular}}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\newpage\mbox{ }
\newpage\mbox{ }
\end{document}
```

Also, as you can see, at the moment the number are aligned to center of a square using additional spaces and \vspace and it's not done precisely. Is there any possibility to do it better?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a suggestion using `tikz`:

[image]

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[left=3.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{red-fiz}{RGB}{194,0,11}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[RO]{%
    \tikz[baseline=(n.base),line width=3pt,minimum size=2em]{
      \node[anchor=base east](n)at(0,0){\thepage};
      \draw[red-fiz]([xshift=-.5\pgflinewidth]n.north east)--(n.north west)
        --(n.south west)--(n.south west-|({-\textwidth+.5\pgflinewidth},0);}%
}
\fancyfoot[LE]{%
    \tikz[baseline=(n.base),line width=3pt,minimum size=2em]{
      \node[anchor=base west](n)at(0,0){\thepage};
      \draw[red-fiz]([xshift=.5\pgflinewidth]n.north west)--(n.north east)
        --(n.south east)--(n.south east-|({\textwidth-.5\pgflinewidth},0);}%
}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{21}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\Blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative that doesn't use a `tabular`. Instead, the rules are set using a collection of `\rule`s (constructed inside a box and re-used):

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{red-fiz}{RGB}{194,0,11}
\usepackage{geometry,graphicx}
\geometry{
  margin=25mm,
  left=35mm,
  showframe,% Just for this example
  paperheight=20\baselineskip% Just for this example
}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\newlength{\frulewidth}\setlength{\frulewidth}{3pt}

\fancyhf{}% Clear fancy header/footer
\fancyfoot[RO]{%
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\usebox{\footerrules}}% Rules
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\makebox[0.1\textwidth][c]{\raisebox{.4\baselineskip}{\thepage}}}% Set the page number
}
\fancyfoot[LE]{%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\reflectbox{\usebox{\footerrules}}}% Rules
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\makebox[0.1\textwidth][c]{\raisebox{.4\baselineskip}{\thepage}}}% Set the page number
}

\newsavebox{\footerrules}
\savebox{\footerrules}{% Construct the default (Right Odd page) rule
  \color{red-fiz}% Rule colour
  \rule{0.9\textwidth}{\frulewidth}% Lower horizontal
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\rule{\frulewidth}{\dimexpr1.5\baselineskip+\frulewidth}}% Vertical
  \rule[1.5\baselineskip]{0.1\textwidth}{\frulewidth}% Upper horizontal
}

\begin{document}

\newpage\mbox{}

\newpage\mbox{}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! I actually used Werners' code, which seemed more understandable for me and didn't require other packages. But still, thank you both for quick answers!